# Find/replace string in Powershell, counting up

Tags: powershell

I have a large file with thousands of simple div tags, which I need to index somehow, best by counting up `<div n="00001">...<div n="00002">.......<div n="32002">`.

So, my question is how to get an array into the basic replace command:

```
(Get-Content c:\Texts\mytext.txt).replace('<div>', '<div n="$a">') | Set-Content c:\Texts\mytextneu.txt
```

It would be even better if the resulting id always has 5 digits, as in the example above.

Comment: Will you potentially have more than one `<div>` tag on a single line?

Comment: There are some, but not necessarily so. I could prepare the document in order to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the entire file into a string and use [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) method with a scriptblock replacement:

```
$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('sourcefile.html')
$script:counter = 0
([regex]'<div>').Replace($text, {
    $script:counter++;
    "<div n=`"$('{0:d5}' -f $script:counter)`">"
}) | Out-File output.html -Encoding utf8
```